# RxBinding 'clicks()' method not triggering again when coming back from another activity

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, rx-binding

**I am using 'RxJava binding APIs for Android UI widgets' to trigger click events on buttons or textview.**

PFB code(Edited) that using to trigger the event

```
class BookAgentActivity : BaseActivity(), BookAgentView {

    @Inject
    @field:Named("activity")
    lateinit var compositeDisposable: CompositeDisposable

    @Inject
    lateinit var bookAgentViewModelFactory: BookAgentViewModelFactory

    private lateinit var bookAgentViewModel: BookAgentViewModel

    private lateinit var cityLocalityJson: CityLocalitiesMO


    override fun getLayoutId(): Int {
        return R.layout.activity_book_agent
    }

    override fun initializeDagger() {
        IleApplication.getRoomComponent().inject(this)
    }

    override fun initializeViewModel() {
        bookAgentViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, bookAgentViewModelFactory).get(BookAgentViewModel::class.java)
        bookAgentViewModel.setView(this)
    }

    override fun setUpUi() {
        gradientStatusBar()
        cityLocalityJson = appPreferences.cityLocalitiesJson

        compositeDisposable.add(bookAgentCityLocationTV.clicks().observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe {
            startActivity(Intent(this, AreaLocalitiesActivity::class.java)
                .putExtra(AppConstants.COMING_FROM_AGENT_KEY, true))
        })

        compositeDisposable.add(filtersButton.clicks().observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe {
            startActivity(Intent(this, FiltersMainActivity::class.java)
                .putExtra(AppConstants.FILTER_TYPE_KEY, AppConstants.AGENT_FILTER))
        })

        compositeDisposable.add(searchAgentsButton.clicks()
            .subscribe { startActivity(Intent(this@BookAgentActivity, SearchAgentActivity::class.java)) })

    }

    override fun onSuccess(response: Any) {
        if (response is AgentsDetailAPIResponse) {
            response.let {
                val agentDetailsList = it.data
                if (agentDetailsList != null && agentDetailsList.size > 0) {
                    updateAgentPinsOnMap(agentDetailsList)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        compositeDisposable.clear()
    }
}
```

**:) Above code works fine for the first time**

**:(** But after coming back from **BookAgentActivity (onBackPressed())**

Click events are not working for **searchAgentsButton** as well as for **other views** too.

> Have tried including combinations of other lines of code like below:

```
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.share()
```

But none of the above things are working.

Comment: Not sure, but could it be because it's a disposable?

Comment: Please post a bigger snippet. When are you subscribing, onStart() onCreate()? When are unsubscribing, disposing etc? This sounds like a lifecycle and subscription issue.

Comment: where you used `compositeDisposable.clear()` or `Dispoosable.dispose()` methods in code

Comment: @GiorgosNeokleous  FYI Subscribing in onCreate() and unsubscribing in onDestroy() {compositeDisposable.clear()}

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're using RxBinding for this, rather than just set an onClickListener?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce : No, there is not any particular reason just wanna try RxBinding. But unfortunately facing the above mentioned issue..